# Remember spelling settings in session file

Tags: spell-checking, sessions

I enabled spell checking in a buffer with `set spell spelllang=en` which works. If I save the session with `mksession!` and later source it back with `vim -S Session.vim`, spellchecking is no longer enabled.

How can I save spell checking an spell language in a Session file (and apply it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `spell` and `spelllang` options are local options and by default sessions only store global options.

You can change this behavior by updating [`sessionoptions`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27sessionoptions%27) to also include `localoptions`:

```
set sessionoptions+=localoptions
```

The reason why local options are typically not stored in a session file is that they're normally managed by per-filetype plugins, and those plug-ins will be reloaded when the session is restored. Not storing local options gives the plug-ins the opportunity to set options differently, which might be useful or relevant when restoring a session after upgrading plug-ins.